# Is there a way to create avatars?

Tags: photos

I have not set my avatar, so is there any recommended web application for creating an avatar?
(If the app can import photos, that will be nice)

Comment: Do you want an app to create an avatar, or set your avatar?

Comment: create. like an image editor does.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your user page and edit your picture, it will redirect you to [Gravatar](http://www.gravatar.com/) , easy and useful to associate your avatar with your email address.

Answer (score 1):

Really, any standard image can be used as avatar.
But I know only one website dedicated to avatar creation : [Eightbit.me](http://eightbit.me) is a service to help people create 8-bit avatars.